# What's the difference between veriable and veriable with brackets in PHP?

Tags: php, brackets

1. `$db["db_name"] = "users";`
2. `$db_name = "users";`

How will example 1 be different from example 2?

Comment: It will be completely different. What **exactly** is your question about this?

Comment: How are these two variables different

Comment: Why not dump them to see the difference? `$db["db_name"]` isn't even a variable on its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to break things down in order to simplify them.

- `$db["db_name"] = "users";`: that would make `$db` an associative array where the string `"db_name"` is a key in that array and `"users"` is the value for the `"db_name"` key in the `$db` array. When you call `echo $db["db_name"]` the text `users` will be printed to the screen.
- `$db_name = "users";`: that means that `$db_name` is a variable where `"users"` is its value. So when calling `echo $db_name` the result will be `users` (printed to the screen).

In `PHP` you can use a variable (its value to be precise) as an array index which allows you retrieve the value at that index from an array, an example:

```
$db_name = "users"; // this will act as an index
$db[$db_name] = "some value"; // the index "user" which is the value of the variable "$db_name" holds the value "some value" in the "$db" variable
echo $db_name . ' | ' . $db[$db_name]; // prints: users | some value
```

Here's a [live demo](https://3v4l.org/Bdoha#v7.4.30) for the code above.

So to summarize, `$db["db_name"] = "users"` create an array with `"db_name"` as a key in that array that holds the value `"users"` where the other one, `$db_name = "users"`, create a variable that holds the string `users`.

Answer (score 1):

The first is an array named `db` which has an element with index `db_name`; the second is a scalar named `db_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are a way to print a value from an array.

`$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");`

```
$age['Peter'] = "35";
$age['Ben'] = "37";
$age['Joe'] = "43";
```

Comment: No, brackets means that the variable is an array. Please check my answer for more details.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I managed to help you even a little bit.